# XCode Simulator CoreData not stored: Where to call save managed context?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have a parent and a child managed context. I call the parent managed context to save its data in two methods:

- applicationWillTerminate
- applicationDidEnterBackground

When I am using the simulator and just clicking the "stop" button at the top, neither is called and the context not saved. On the phone itself of course when normally using the app everything works like a charm. If I click the "Home" button in the simulator and go back to the app and then terminate, then of course it is saved because applicationDidEnterBackground was called.

So either I probably have to add somewhere else to save the background context if the simulator is right, or this is a bug of the simulator, or I exit the simulator wrongly. Can you help me? Do I need to change anything or should I just use the "trick" in the simulator to store the data?

Comment: I think pushing the stop button simply kills the process without saving the app state.

Comment: stop button is treated as soft crash, such scenario  is not reproducible in real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK to save your data in those methods but they should not be the only place you do so. Things can go wrong that are out of your control, and it would be good to not lose user data when they do. For example, maybe the phone's battery will suddenly die when your app has a lot of unsaved changes in memory. You're doing a good job of simulating this kind of situation, actually.

Also, the more unsaved changes you have, the more memory your app needs. If you save data, you can always look it up later, so Core Data can clear out its caches, re-fault objects, etc.

**You should save changes whenever new changes exist that should not be lost.** Exactly when that is depends on your app, but it's almost certainly more than just in those two methods. A common pattern is that any time the UI indicates the user has completed some task, the data related to that task should be saved.